# Workflow Foundation 4 Custom Activity Design without rehosted Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, workflow-foundation-4

Is it possible to make custom Designers for my Workflow Activities without the use of a custom rehosted Designer?

I am running Visual Studio 2013 with .NET 4.5

In the official documentation, this possibility is not mentioned: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489419(v=vs.110).aspx

I remember, that I read about it, but can not remember the url.

Comment: Yes, of course.  Try it.  If you place your designer in a different DLL and refer to it by type name rather than by reference&type, you have to put the design dll in a special folder under visual studio.

Comment: Yes, but WITHOUT this special folder?

Comment: The designer class has to be in the same assembly as the activity.